# VBA timer is not cleared of StatusBar

Tags: excel, vba

I put a time on the status bar to count how long a macro takes to finish. My problem is i want to clear off the status bar after say 10 seconds after the end otherwise the time will be there the whole time, I hope i make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use:

```
application.StatusBar = false
```

to reset the status bar to its default text.